# doubt with the proposition used

Tags: sentence

Is there any correction required for this sentence, **She's waiting for people to respond by the invitations they sent out**, is by the right preposition to use, if not then why ? and why can we use ** to instead of by ** ??

Comment: Hi Sandra. It is a matter of the verb. You *wait* (for people) **to** + Verb. He waited for his friends to arrive. She waited for the traffic light to turn green. If that is the extent of your question, then it is better asked on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I advocate the use of 'to' in this regard:

[Check Cambridge Advanced Learners](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/dicionario/ingles/respond) it is a great dictionary that highlights the correct use of prepositions. I tend to believe that it's the only dictionary that has the various uses of prepositions highlighted in the examples.

Examples
I want to respond **to** something that Norman said.
He responded **by** marching off and slamming the door behind him.

As you can see, **by** is used to refer to the subject that responds rather than the recipient/receiver.